# What items are shown in this panel of All-Star Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, object-identification

This panel from *All-Star Superman* shows part of Superman's Fortress of Solitude.

[image: Superman's stuff]

(Note that "Superman's Forbidden Room" is the name of the story, not the area shown.)

You can see the city of Kandor to the left. Have any of the other items been shown in previous Superman comics?

Comment: One of them is the penny that is usually in the Batcave.

Comment: @TheDoctor I noticed that, but this penny has the Joker on it, unlike Batman's.

Comment: There's the Titanic, the Columbia (was this post '02?), a chessboard with jimmy, perry, lois, batman, bizarre, brainiac, and luthor

Comment: Ha That is awesome @RogueJedi -- I did not even notice that it was the joker on there till I zoomed in.

Comment: Bottled city of Kandor (obviously) and what looks like a Legion Time Bubble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Left to Right

- The [RMS Titanic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0tSB.png)
- The Bottle City of Kandor
- The [Space Shuttle Columbia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELVRv.jpg)
- Superman's [Giant Penny](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yESwC.png) (not to be confused with Batman's [Giant Penny](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Giant_Penny))
- A [Kryptonian Battle Suit](http://static.srcdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/Fortress-of-Solutide-Kryptonian-Battlesuit.jpg)(?)
- A giant chessboard with various [waxwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvVDn.png) characters (Jimmy Olsen, Perry White, Lois Lane, Batman, Bizarro, Brainiac, and Lex Luthor).
- A [Time-Bubble](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Bubble)

Comment: @RogueJedi - I think that one might be a tip of the hat to "Red Sun" where we see the Titanic in Superman's fortress; http://theages.superman.nu/History/2000/titanic.jpg

Comment: @RogueJedi - Or this image from Superman #71; http://i.stack.imgur.com/n0tSB.png

Comment: @RogueJedi in a couple of pages before, he mentions how he has picked up Archaeology as a hobby

Comment: What the hell is that glowy thing far right?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think that's meant to be a Kryptonian Battle Suit. Those were single-user suits that functioned to keep the wearer isolated from their environment and didn't have see-through heads. This thing has two seats in the head and you can see into the cockpit. I'm not sure what it is, but I'm fairly sure it's not a Kryptonian Battle Suit.

Comment: The Columbia one seems like it's in poor taste to me.

Comment: @roguejedi - He did save it several times in the comics.